# On Android, is it possible to send an intent to the Google maps application with a custom marker image specified in the intent?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-markers

The default Google maps marker is a red pin. Is it possible to replace the default marker image with a custom image through an intent?

Edit:
This is when sending a geouri intent to launch an external map app. Not when doing it within the app with a MapActivity subclass.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I forgot to clarify that I was asking about sending an intent to an external map app. Question edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send an Integer with the image position in the array:

```
Intent i = new Intent (yourClass.this, MapActivity.class)
i.putExtra("pinPosition",2);
startActivity(i);
```

And in your map activity:

```
 public class MyMapActivity extends MapActivity {
    private int drawables[] = { R.drawable.pin1, R.drawable.pin2, R.drawable.tutorial_pin3 };
    int position;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (getIntent().getSerializableExtra("pinPosition")!=null) {
        position = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("pinPosition");
            }

            setContentView(R.layout.publish_map_activity);
            map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
            ImageView pin = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.drag);
            pin.setImageResource(drawables[position]);
    ....

    }

    }
```

If you use a similar google code, your xml should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="@string/googlemaps_key"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/drag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:src="@drawable/mapitempng"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I forgot to specify that I was asking about sending an intent to an external map app. But I hope this helps anyone trying to use a custom image marker on their map views within their apps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I just hope that I've got your question correctly:
You can do it through Overlay Items. Just check **[THIS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview)** example from Google itself:
You can customize any marker by specifying a drawable.